# How to match an unsorted column in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the below 4 columns. The "Name1 Sorted" is a group of values that are sorted, and the "ID sorted" is the id for each value. I have the same "Name1" but it is unsorted. How can I use Vlookup or any other way to match the "ID unsorted" to its corresponding "Name1 unsorted" column ?

[image]

Comment: You mentioned `VLOOKUP()` but haven't researched how to implement it? To be honest, just googling the documentation would take less time than posting on SO =). The quality of your (future) post(s) can increase significantly if you have a look at [ask] a question with an [mcve] including your own efforts in solving your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `Index/Match` combination.

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$8,MATCH(C2,$A$2:$A$8,0))
```

[image]

With <kbd>Microsoft365</kbd> you can use `XLOOKUP()`

```
=XLOOKUP(C2,$A$2:$A$8,$B$2:$B$8,"No ID")
```

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case you can also use vlookup:

```
=VLOOKUP(C2,$A$2:$B$8,2,TRUE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can also use `vlookup()` Function for exact match:

[image]